# How to make failed sidekiq job retry with new production Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I'm running a Rails 5.0.x application on Heroku with Sidekiq/Redis and I deployed new code that a failed Sidekiq job that is retrying multiple times should be using.

In https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ, I see:

> Rails has two features which are relevant here: eager loading and
>   autoloading. Autoloading is only active in development mode and is not
>   thread-safe so Sidekiq disables it and uses eager loading only. Eager
>   loading loads your code only once when starting the server - it does
>   not reload your code between jobs. If you have code located outside of
>   the standard Rails directories (e.g. app/models, app/controllers,
>   etc), Sidekiq will not see it unless you add the path to
>   eager_load_paths in your Rails application configuration:

```
# in config/application.rb
module AcmeCorp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.eager_load_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib/workers"]
  end
end
```

"Because Sidekiq does not reload code between jobs", does this mean I can't use the new rails production code without starting a new job?  Or if I restart the failed job, will it use the newly deployed code?

Answer (score 4):

Deploying new code to Heroku will automatically restart all your dynos including worker dynos. So you don't have to restart it manually. And of course after restarting Sidekiq will pick up new code.

Comment: Hmm..I wonder why then my Sidekiq retry appears to be using the old code according to our error reporting system?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I think the implication of this:

> Autoloading is only active in development mode and is not thread-safe
>   so Sidekiq disables it and uses eager loading only. Eager loading
>   loads your code only once when starting the server - it does not
>   reload your code between jobs.

means that you have to restart sidekiq on Heroku after you deploy.

Which you can do with a `heroku ps:restart worker -a myapp`